# Get Stores Details by website id in one website - multiple stores scenario

Tags: magento-1.9, websites, stores

I am working on one website - multiple stores platform. How i can get store details by website id.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can get it like that...

```
$websiteId=1;
    $website = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($websiteId); 
    foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
            $stores = $group->getStores();
            foreach ($stores as $store) {
                echo $store->getId() ." ".$store->getName()."<br/>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Working correctly....